# How can I find defination of GPIO in linux, especially for beaglebone black?

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I just want to know if there a header file in Linux 3.8 to describes `GPIO` ports for hardware board, especially for Beaglebone black board. There are four groups of `GPIO` in Beaglebone Black board, and there are 32 GPIOs in each group. So I guess that a `GPIO` in `GROUP X(0 <= X <= 3) PORT Y (0 <= Y <= 31)`, will map to GPIO port `(32 * X + Y)`. For an example, `GPIO12` in `GROUP1` is `GPIO44`, and we can use 44 when I use Linux `GPIO` APIs. So when I use some APIs like "gpio_is_valid", I can set the parameter as 44. Because I want to write a Linux driver for some devices, I really need to know how it defined. I am not concerned about how to control `GPIO`s in user space.

Thanks so much.

Comment: You'll need to research this.  I think the term "pin mux" is what you need to continue your research.  This occurs at various different levels, for example: xload, uboot, then later in the kernel. If you need to define the behavior the moment power is applied to the board, defining the muxing in xloader is necessary; and while booting the kernel, defining the muxing in uboot is necessary--and that's assuming the Beaglebone is using xload and uboot (as the original Beagleboard), which may not be the case.

Comment: YOu are looking for a *library* - a headee file alone will not be sufficient.

Comment: I think 3.8 may have been the last release before it moved to *devicetree* format for hardware descriptions.

Comment: Based on my experience with several Atmel SoCs, there usually is no header file in Linux kernel source with the info you seek. I could find **#defines** for the base address of each GPIO controller in the header file of SoC peripherals in **arch/arm/mach-xxx/include/mach/**. But the number of pins per controller was usually defined in the board file or the Device Tree. For Linux userland code I've had to manually import SoC header files from bare-metal software packages to get the headers files that had GPIO register names and bit fields.

Comment: Thanks all of you above!!

Comment: @myninjaname I think "pin mux"is what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel picks up the default pin muxing from the boot environment.  To control the pin behavior without using the user space, you can patch the boot environment.  X-Loader (MLO) is first loaded, which loads the U-Boot environment (u-boot.bin), which loads the kernel.

Keep in mind that my knowledge of this is from 2011, so there may be a better way to accomplish this in later builds... Also, I was using the Gumstix Overo (which is similar to the BeagleBoard).  It looks like the BeagleBone Black uses the same boot environment as the original BeagleBoard, so I'll give it a try to answer your question (I'm referencing files used by the BeagleBoard, which may be different for the BeagleBoard Black).

In order to control the GPIO behavior for when the device is first powered on, you can patch X-Loader to define the needed pin muxing:

```
x-loader:
board/omap3530beagle/omap3530beagle.c
include/asm/arch-omap3/mux.h # review to match pin assignments to the technical manual
```

X-Loader (MLO) will then load the U-Boot environment.  In order to control how the kernel initially handles the pin muxing, and during the loading of the kernel (IIRC), you can patch U-Boot to define the needed pin muxing:

```
u-boot:
board/ti/beagle/beagle.h
arch/arm/include/asm/arch-omap3/mux.h # review to match pin assignments to the technical manual
```

Once booted, you can toggle or read the GPIOs in user space :).

Also, pin muxing could be changed in user space on the Overo using devmem2, so unless you need to control the default behavior (such as keeping a pin low to keep a device powered off), it will be much easier to use something like devmem2.

Answer (score 1):

The BeagleBone project's web-site has a library called [BlackLib](http://beagleboard.org/project/blacklib/) that provides a GPIO, ADC and PWM API for C++.  Also [this](http://www.element14.com/community/community/designcenter/single-board-computers/next-gen_beaglebone/blog/2013/10/10/bbb--beaglebone-black-io-library-for-c) for C.